# getting list of videos from youtube using youtube data api v3 with php

Tags: php, youtube, google-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

i have a problem getting a list of my uploded youtube videos, i think im following the documentation corectly but i always get the error "Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular: (403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

below is my code

```
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'myclientid';
        $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'myclientsecret';


        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
        $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);


        $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
        $redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
                FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);




        // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
        $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);


        $m = $youtube->videos->listVideos('contentDetails', ['chart' => 'mostPopular','mine' => true]);




var_dump($m->items());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

You need to sign up and get an Youtube Data API Key.

See this page for information on how to optain a authorization:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application

Using a valid api token the given request works:
Request URI: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&key=my-working-api-key

Response:

```
 {
     "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
     "etag": "\"VWxPoEGGsFABuqUjd074WYFuSzg/nDAVTxNMgQ9F4nGTs7fZaznFTOk\"",
     "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
     "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 200,
      "resultsPerPage": 5
     },
     "items": [
      {
       "kind": "youtube#video",
       "etag": "\"VWxPoEGGsFABuqUjd074WYFuSzg/_msWCTIjlV0IjeLHHznnkaF88sE\"",
       "id": "oZRh6J9ezfw",
       "contentDetails": {
        "duration": "PT5M43S",
        "dimension": "2d",
        "definition": "hd",
        "caption": "false",
        "licensedContent": true,
        "regionRestriction": {
         "blocked": [
          "ZW",
          "ZM",
        ...
```

Comment: i do have an api key, client id and client secret. no matter what i try its not working. its says "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded" but it didnt work from the start

Comment: All i can say is:
The given query works as intended when using a valid API Key of the YouTube Data API V3.
I dont know what u mean by "client id" and "client secret" - you need neither of those to access the webservice.

Please see the guide to obtain an access token - that one worked for me.

Comment: not for me clearly! i tried my developer API key and now the error changed to "Access not configured". and its asking me to check my referrer set up. and even that matches my domain exactly so i really dont know where the error is coming from now :(

Comment: When setting up your API key you have to enter all ip's which should be able to access the API trough the key. Plesse check if those are set correctly (i use ip's there, dont know if it works with domains as the domain does point to the server but the server still describes himself with an ip).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. the problem as i mentioned on my last comment was the referees. i restricted it to my website but that didnt work as it kept saying "access not configured!". but now removed the restriction and allowed all referees IT WORKS :).

might not be as secure now, but since its only me who have the developer key i think it will be fine.